# Regex expression for Changing close brackets to open brackets

Tags: json, regex

I have a JSON text full of these:

```
  "order": "Commande",
  "@order":    }
    "description": "order word",
    "type": "texte"
  },
```

As you can see, There is an error in front of `"@Order:"` which `}` is used instead of `{`

How can I replace all of them with open bracket without changing `}`, at the end of objects? (I mean I need the regex expression to use it in search of my text editor)

`^\s\}{1}\s` didn't work

Comment: No need to repost questions, you could just update your previous one. Note `^\s\}\s` matches a whitespace, `}` and whitespace at the start of string. Your `}` is at the *end* of string (line here).

Comment: Try `:\h*\K\}(?=\h*$)` and replace with `{`. See https://regex101.com/r/UpDO9h/1

Comment: Yes, you can update your question so long as your update does not invalidate any correct answers for the state of the question at the time those correct answers were given.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ```\}$``` worked.

Comment: If my answer does not help you solve the issue, please consider updating the question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you

```
(?<=\"@\w+\":\s+)}
```

https://regex101.com/r/A4Yv6X/1

Answer (score 1):

Your `^\s\}\s` pattern matches a whitespace, `}` and whitespace at the *start* of string. while the `}` you want to replace is at the *end* of string (or line).

You may consider using `\}$`, or `\}(?=\s*$)`, or `\}(?=\h*$)` patterns to match `}` only at the end of a string/line (where `$` is the end of string/line, `(?=\s*$)` matches a location that is immediately followed with any 0 or more whitespaces and then the end of a string/line, `\h` just only allows horizontal whitespaces).

However, if there is a colon before the `}` you need to replace you may consider a more sophisticated pattern like

```js
(:\h*)\}(\h*$)
(:[^\S\r\n]*)\}([^\S\r\n]*$)
```

Replace with `$1{$2` (or `\1{\2` depending on the environment).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UpDO9h/2/). Details:

- `(:\h*)` - Capturing group 1 (`$1`): a colon and zero or more horizontal whitespaces
- `\}` - a `}` char
- `(\h*$)` - Group 2 (`$2`): zero or more horizontal whitespaces.

Note that `[^\S\r\n]` is a rough equivalent to `\h`, it matches any whitespace char but CR and LF chars.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, which matches brackets at the ends of lines

```
(?m)\}$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/cg06tLOMxs0vSZ).

Depending on your input, this might be enough.